# How many ways to arrange 4 letters in 10 spaces

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If we have a set of $4$ letters {A, B, C, D}, and we have $10$ spaces to put these $4$ letters in, how many ways can we arrange these $4$ letters in these $10$ spaces? It is important to note that

A B C D _ _ _ _ _ _

is different from

_ A B C D _ _ _ _ _.

Both of those are obviously different from

B A C D _ _ _ _ _ _

and

_ B A C D _ _ _ _ _.

My thinking is that we have $10$ spaces, so it should at least be $10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7$. I am unsure if we also need to multiply this by $4!$ to signify that there are $24$ different ways to pick the order of the letters. If we don't need to multiply it $4!$ why would we not need to?

Comment: I agree with the answer, that confirms that your initial computation of $$10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7$$ is good.  This computation is justified by reasoning that you have $(10)$ choices for the A, then $(9)$ choices for the $B$, and so forth.  The alternative approach is $$\binom{10}{4} \times 4!$$ which results in the same computation, and is justified by reasoning that there are $~\displaystyle \binom{10}{4}~$ ways of selecting which $(4)$ positions will be used.  Then, once the positions are selected, there are $(4!)$ ways of ordering the $(4)$ letters.

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking is correct however don’t multiply it by $4!$, and since order matters this is a permutation, which can be calculated as follows:

$$\frac{10!}{(10-4)!}=10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7=5040$$

different to pick the different orders of letters.

Consider the fact that each time a letter from the set is being placed into a space, it cannot go anywhere else i.e. repeated elsewhere. So each time we place a letter we are doing so without repetition. We must do this four times which is why we got $10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7$.

However, if we multiply this permutation by $4!$, we are effectively saying that we have $4!$ amount of sets of four alphabets placed in ten spaces that have $10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7$ of permutations. In other words, we would be overcounting/overdoing the problem significantly by $4!$.

More information on permutations is available [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html)